# Elasticsearch query Combine 2 queries or Elastic search Join Query

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch

This is my one elastic document example:

```
"_source": {
    "leg_b":{
            "team_name" : "aaaa",
            "channel_uuid" : "12121"
    },  
    wrapup":[
      "0":{
            "name": "sss",
            "channel_uuid": "12121"
          },
      "1":{
            "name": "bbb",
            "channel_uuid" : "21212"
          },
      "2":{
            "name": "acbs",
            "channel_uuid" : "111211"
          }
     ]
}
```

I have to perform search on "leg_b.team_name" value and find out its "channel_uuid" value on the basis of leg_b's "channel_uuid",NEXT I will search in wrapup object for common "channel_uuid" values **in the Same Query**.

**Example**,
lets consider above document, First I will **search** on leg_b.team_name = "aaaa" after that I will take **leg_b.channel_uuid = "12121"** and **search** on **wrapup object channel_uuid**.
Explaination:
So there are two searches are going on 1) leg_b.team_name="aaaa" which returns this document and after that 2) on the returned doc which I got from 1st search, I will take its leg_b.channel_uuid to search on wrapup common channel uuid. (i.e, leg_b channel_uuid is "12121" so I should get "wrapup" channel_uuid : "12121" objects. It exclude "acbc" because its channel_uuid : "111211".

```
So it should return,
"_source": {
"leg_b":{
        "team_name" : "aaaa",
        "channel_uuid" : "12121"
},  
"wrapup":[
  "0":{
        "name": "sss",
        "channel_uuid": "12121"
      },
  "1":{
        "name": "bbb",
        "channel_uuid" : "21212"
      }
      ]
}
```

Please suggest some approach, Thank you.

Comment: Can you add more clarification of query and response ? why `"name": "acbs"` is not coming in response ?

Comment: @SagarPatel I added extra explaination, Please check.